# What is the term to describe the following situation about crime?

Tags: word-usage

What is the word to describe the following:
A man goes into crime, and is successful at it which causes him to bring his son into crime. His son is successful, but doesn't bring his son in because he sees all of the bad things it brought into his life and his father's life.

Comment: He didn't bring his son into the family business.

Comment: It's the plot of *The Godfather*. The book is 448 pages long - you want to sum it up in a word?

Comment: I knew this word at one time, but since forgotten it. There is a word for this, and this is what I am looking for because it does happen very often.

Comment: It’s called having a conscience, putting an end to things ...

Answer (score 1):

Though probably not what you are looking for, a Talmudic simile might come useful here: "Wine, son of Vinegar", meaning a righteous son of a reprobate father.

Originally, the opposite expression "Vinegar, son of Wine" was used, as documented [here](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=RjAI9SVRnUkC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=vinegar%20the%20son%20of%20wine&source=bl&ots=da0mCuFeQk&sig=mhD3p-PP-HM1ppf2SNrz4LKMrlM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3qf38orzQAhUEVhQKHdHIC2oQ6AEIRDAJ#v=onepage&q=vinegar%20&f=false), but in modern Hebrew both versions seem to have equal footing.

Self-criticism: What my suggestion misses, though, is the agency of the father in keeping his son away from his life of crime.

Comment: The average oenologist will scratch his head at this one unless he happens to be a Talmudic scholar in which case he just might be able to rationalize "Wine, son of Vinegar" when wine always turns into vinegar over time but never vinegar into wine (alas). I'm sure Rashi, who was a grape grower and winemaker, would have had something to say on this, what?

Answer (score 1):

Daniel Bell, American sociologist, wrote a book first published in 1960: *The End of Ideology*, with a chapter titled "Crime as an American Way of Life: A Queer Ladder of Social Mobility", in which he describes organized crime figures adopting typical middle-class American values, sending their children to college, etc.  It is the non-fiction version of The Godfather.  (Note that today he would have used "Strange" instead of "Queer".) Wikipedia's page on Organized Crime describes Bell's theory as follows:

Bell's theory of the 'queer ladder of mobility' hypothesized that 'ethnic succession' (the attainment of power and control by one more marginalized ethnic group over other less marginalized groups) occurs by promoting the perpetration of criminal activities within a disenfranchised or oppressed demographic.

A single word?  Adapting? Becoming Americanized?  Integrating into American culture?

Probably **acculturation**.

Answer (score -3):

This is tough. Maybe *expatriation* could work? I'm clutching.

***[Expatriate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/expatriate)*** (Oxford)

> A person who lives outside their native country

For example, "There are 200,000 Australian expatriates living in the United States." This *could* be suitable in your instance in the sense that the son is expatriating the grandson from crime.

Comment: Did you look that up?

Comment: No, it's a term used in Australia with regularity. More so ex-patriots, or ex-pats colloquially.

Comment: And what does it mean?